# Testflight beta not sending email or push notification to external testers

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I have started testing for my ios app in testflight but my external testers don't get email or push  notifications to update and test the app, I have about a 35 external testers, none of them are getting notified when I start Testing for a particular build of iOS app after it has passed the beta-app  review.

what could be the issue , can anybody help??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't set that user should be notified when you upload a new version for testing.
- In iTunesConnect open "Users and Roles" and tap on an user.
- Tap on "Notifications" tab
- Set that user gets "App Status Reports" for "All Territories" or some of them. (see picture)

[image]

Comment: That is for internal testers, My external tester are not getting notifies, whenever I upload a new build for testing.